# Home network LAN vs Wireless and Homegroup

Tags: networking, lan, home-networking, gateway, homegroup

I was trying to share my music folder from PC 1 on my local network so that I could access it on my laptop.  I thought it would be as easy as sharing the folder in the folder options on PC 1, which I did.  When I went to the laptop I found that I still couldn't browse to that folder.  So I checked to see if PC 1 was on the Homegroup.  It wasn't, so I created a Homegroup, and joined PC 1 to it.  Then I went to my laptop, and I couldn't find the Homegroup I just created.  I plugged my laptop in to switch 2, found the Homegroup, and joined it.  Then I could see my music folder.  I would like to understand more about LANs, Homegroups, etc.  I have the following devices:

- PC 1:
  IP: 198.216.122.5
  Subnet: 255.255.255.0
  Default Gateway: 198.216.122.1
  DHCP: 104.217.158.128
- PC 2:
  IP: 198.216.123.104
  Subnet: 255.255.255.128
  Default Gateway: 198.216.123.1
  DHCP: 104.217.158.128
- Laptop (Wireless adapter):
  IP: 192.168.1.112
  Subnet: 255.255.255.0
  Default Gateway: 192.168.0.1
  DHCP: 192.168.0.1
- Laptop (Ethernet adapter):
  IP: 198.216.123.99
  Subnet: 255.255.255.128
  Default Gateway: 198.216.123.1
  DHCP: 104.217.158.128

I am not totally unfamiliar with networking, but I would still say I'm a beginner, close to intermediate.  My questions are:

1. How are PC 1 and my laptop (with Ethernet cable plugged in to switch 2) on different subnets, with different default gateways, but have the same DHCP?  My understanding is that LANs are separated by subnets, and my assumption was that Homegroups functioned within the LAN.  If my laptop and PC 1 are on different subnets, aren't they also on different LANs?  And, if they're on different LANs, how are they on the same Homegroup?
2. Is the default gateway what connects my computers to layer 3 devices like routers?  Again, my understanding is that LANs are on layer 2 and require layer 3 devices in order to communicate between LANs.  I don't recognize the IP of the default gateway.  Is that the switches?  (Sorry, multiple questions)
3. My laptop has a wireless adapter, obviously, as well as an Ethernet adapter.  I have not quite been able to sort out how I was only able to join the Homegroup when I plugged in to the switch with an Ethernet cable.  Is that because my wireless adapter puts me on layer 3, while my Ethernet cable puts me on layer 2?

Thank you for your time, and patience (hopefully!) while I piece together this puzzle.

Image of my home network:
[image: My Home Network]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple questions.  I decided to answer what I could easily, and it exceeded the length of one comment.  So then I placed it into an answer and added more details.

This is not a full answer.  I haven't really used Homegroups extensively.  They are supposed to make things easier for people who don't know networking, I guess.  I have worked on networks professionally and gotten by without using Home Groups at all (and resolved some problems by stopping the usage of Home Groups), and had no problems because of that.

> How are PC 1 and my laptop (with Ethernet cable plugged in to switch 2) on different subnets, with different default gateways, but have the same DHCP?

I imagine this could be "DHCP relay".  Not very common, but part of the DHCP standard.  After a client sends out a DISCOVER message, DHCP's response needs to come from the same subnet.  Most commonly, a response is provided by a DHCP Server that keeps track of leases.  However, the response could come from a DHCP Relay agent that is on the same subnet.  This DHCP Relay agent would have an IP address, so it could communicate with IP to the DHCP server which may be on a different subnet.  My guess is that the DHCP address you're seeing is the address of the DHCP server.

> My understanding is that LANs are separated by subnets

A subnet is a collection of addresses.  Typically I've seen an entire LAN use one setting for a subnet.  Wi-Fi may be mixed into the same subnet as Ethernet, or be a separate subnet.

This is what I've most commonly seen actually deployed, but when you specify how big of subnets you are using, and the purpose of each subnet, you can have some options.

> If my laptop and PC 1 are on different subnets, aren't they also on different LANs?

When I think of the word "LAN" (a "local area network") is basically: a network at one location.  Typically that's just one building, or maybe also including some cabling out to a nearby building that has fewer than 5 computers.  If you get bigger than that, especially with notably different locations (with different physical street addresses), you're generally dealing with a WAN ("wide area network").  I'm not offhand thinking of an exact definition that specifies what is a LAN and what is a WAN.  I believe that may be open to some different opinions.

Since there is typically just one Ethernet LAN per subnet, using the terms LAN and subnet interchangeably may work fairly well, usually.

The definition of an IP subnet is going to be much more technically precise.  An IP subnet has a bunch of IP addresses.  An IP subnet will have a starting address, and a size.  (Based on the size, you can figure out the ending address.)

> Is the default gateway what connects my computers to layer 3 devices like routers?

Typically, yes.  The point of a subnet is for a computer to figure out what to do with network traffic.

- If a computer is part of the same subnet as the destination, then the traffic will be sent directly to the destination by making a(n Ethernet or Wi-Fi) frame that will go straight to the destination's Layer 2 MAC-48 address.

  - That MAC-48 address will be figured out using NDP (if using IPv6) or ARP (if using IPv4).
- If the destination is part of another building, and so the traffic needs to be sent to the router that gets information to that building, then the traffic will go to the "gateway" of the destination subnet.  That "gateway" would be a router.  You might see this happen if you have multiple buildings, like at a college campus.

  - The (Ethernet or Wi-Fi) frame will be sent to the MAC-48 address of the router.  The MAC-48 address of that router will be figured out by taking the IP address of the router and using NDP (if using IPv6) or ARP (if using IPv4).  Inside that frame, the IP packet will still have the IP address of the desired final destination.
- If there isn't a more specific subnet to use, then the computer will typically use the "gateway of last resort", also (more commonly) known as the "default gateway", which gets used whenever there isn't a more specific route to use.

  - Just like with the last main bullet point...
    The (Ethernet or Wi-Fi) frame will be sent to the MAC-48 address of the router.  The MAC-48 address of that router will be figured out by taking the IP address of the router and using NDP (if using IPv6) or ARP (if using IPv4).  Inside that frame, the IP packet will still have the IP address of the desired final destination.

These "gateway" devices are called routers.

If your computer decides that a router needs to be used, then the computer will place the IP packet into a(n Ethernet or Wi-Fi) frame that gets sent to the router's MAC-48 address.  If no router is needed, the computer will place the IP packet into a(n Ethernet or Wi-Fi) frame that gets sent to the des

> Again, my understanding is that LANs are on layer 2 and require layer 3 devices in order to communicate between LANs.

Sounds *about right*, though a bit confusingly.

Devices communicating on Layer 2 will be on the same LAN.  Devices on a LAN communicate using frames that contain MAC-48 addresses.  Using MAC-48 addresses is layer 2.  So, Ethernet or Wi-Fi frames get sent to destination MAC-48 addresses.  This can be done without needing any routing.  When no routing is going on, but IP addresses are being used (typical on modern systems), then all the devices will be on the same subnet.

You'll need a device performing "routing" (typically called a "router") to get traffic from one subnet to another.

Typically, most software today is designed to use IP addresses (which are layer 3), or software uses DNS.  Well, DNS ends up eventually getting converted into an IP address before an IP packet is made.

> I don't recognize the IP of the default gateway.

I don't understand if this is a question.

> Is that the switches? (Sorry, multiple questions)

Cheap switches are usually "dumb" switches.  The term "dumb switch" means the exact same thing as the term "unmanaged switch", so the opposite of a "dumb switch" is a "managed switch".

Dumb switches don't pay any attention to IP addresses at all.

Managed switches do have IP addresses.  They an do fancy things like keeping traffic separated, like routers.  To keep things simple, I suggest not using a managed switch until you are trying to do something complicated enough to have a need for such a thing (like using VLANs to segregate VOIP traffic away from other Ethernet traffic generated by computers).

Just think of unmanaged switches are being "IP-less".  If you do have a "managed switch", which is capable of doing fancy things like "routing" (yeah, unfortunately the lines defining a "switch" vs. a "router" can be a bit blurry), hopefully its default configuring will allow it to work like an unmanaged switch, keeping things simple.

> Is that because my wireless adapter puts me on layer 3, while my Ethernet cable puts me on layer 2?

If your Wi-Fi adapter is functioning fully, being fully configured to communicate with the outside world, then I would expect that your networking software (built into the operating system) will have assigned an IP address to the Wi-Fi adapter.

If your Ethernet adapter is functioning fully, being fully configured to communicate with the outside world, then I would expect that your networking software (built into the operating system) will have assigned an IP address to the Ethernet adapter.

"You" don't have an IP address.  For that matter, neither does your computer.  Your individual NICs do.  (NIC = Network interface card... it is an old term when networking was provided by add-on cards.  You can think of NIC as meaning Network Interface Circuitry if that's easier, although that's not the official meaning of that abbreviation.  So, a NIC is what you call a "network adapter".)

Typically (with simple setups), each fully functioning NIC has its own separate (Layer 3) IP address.  Likewise, each fully functioning NIC has its own (Layer 2) MAC-48 address.

> Thank you for your time, and patience (hopefully!)

Here's another hint that you weren't asking about.

The default gateway needs to be in the subnet.  Therefore, Laptop (Wireless adapter)'s setting of 192.168.1.112/24 (a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 means the same thing as /24), with a default gateway of 192.168.0.1, is an invalid combination of settings.

When I note default gateways in documentation used by other network techs, I often chop off the first part of the address.  e.g., "192.168.1.112/24 DGW=.1".  I don't bother noting that the default gateway starts with "192.168.1" because that is something that is *fully safe* to assume when the IPv4 address starts with "192.168.1." and uses IPv4 /24 as the subnet size.

I would hope the network software (the operating system) would reject such settings.  Otherwise, I would expect this device to have troubles communicating with anything outside of 192.168.1.xxx (so, this should be fixed)

Or, maybe Microsoft Windows does reject such settings, and you typed them down wrong?  Hint: when asking for help, especially in a public forum, make sure that information is accurate.  Otherwise you may lead people astray, turn away people who might otherwise help, and run the risk of being given information that won't work well for you.

> while I piece together this puzzle.

I suggest starting by making sure IP addresses and subnets are assigned accurately, and making sure every device can ping each other device.  (This may require making some exceptions to software firewall settings that block incoming ping traffic by default.)  Then, and only then, try to mess around with file sharing.

My recommendation for Home Groups: Just eliminate them entirely.  In my opinion, they cause conflicts with traditional file sharing which works quite nicely.  If you have a computer at an IP address of 192.0.2.10 and a shared folder named "ShareName", then open up Windows Explorer and point it to \192.0.2.10 (or even \192.0.2.10\ShareName).  To share a folder, access the folder's Properties and on the Sharing tab, choose "Advanced sharing", give it a name, and set the Permissions so that Everyone has Full Control.  (Unless you're on an Active Directory Domain, in which case "Domain Users" is often just as good as "Everyone", and slightly more restrictive of access that is probably unwanted.)  (Microsoft's recommendations to people training as professionals has been to restrict access using NTFS permissions, not share permissions.)

> Thank you for your time, and patience (hopefully!)

Some people have less patience than me.  I would expect this question runs the risk of just being closed.  Please don't make a "question" like this.  The problem with this "question" is that you really had multiple questions.  Instead, break them apart and ask them separately (in separate SuperUser questions).  That makes answering them much easier.  (People can make full answers much quicker/easier.  And you don't have multiple answers that end up answering just part of the question.  It just works much better that way.)